# Azure functions unable to import certain python packages

Tags: python-3.x, azure, azure-functions

when using azure functions I have the problem that certain packages (e.g. azure.kusto.data) can not be installed from the init file.

My init file looks like this:

```
import datetime
import logging
from azure.kusto.data.helpers import dataframe_from_result_table
import azure.functions as func


def main(mytimer: func.TimerRequest) -> None:
    utc_timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(
        tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc).isoformat()

    if mytimer.past_due:
        logging.info('The timer is past due!')

    logging.info('Python timer trigger function ran at %s', utc_timestamp)
```

My requirements.txt file contains:

```
azure-functions
azure-kusto-data
```

The error message is the following:

```
Result: Failure
Exception: AssertionError:
Stack:   File "C:\Users\hanft\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\azure-functions-core-tools\bin\workers\python\3.9/WINDOWS/X64\azure_functions_worker\dispatcher.py", line 301, in _handle__function_load_request
    func = loader.load_function(
  File "C:\Users\hanft\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\azure-functions-core-tools\bin\workers\python\3.9/WINDOWS/X64\azure_functions_worker\utils\wrappers.py", line 40, in call
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\hanft\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\azure-functions-core-tools\bin\workers\python\3.9/WINDOWS/X64\azure_functions_worker\loader.py", line 83, in load_function
    mod = importlib.import_module(fullmodname)
  File "C:\Users\hanft\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 855, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\hanft\Documents\azuretestneu\jobs_creator\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from azure.kusto.data.helpers import dataframe_from_result_table
  File "C:\Users\hanft\Documents\azuretestneu\.venv\lib\site-packages\azure\kusto\data\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .client import KustoClient, KustoConnectionStringBuilder, ClientRequestProperties
  File "C:\Users\hanft\Documents\azuretestneu\.venv\lib\site-packages\azure\kusto\data\client.py", line 22, in <module>
    from .security import _AadHelper
  File "C:\Users\hanft\Documents\azuretestneu\.venv\lib\site-packages\azure\kusto\data\security.py", line 5, in <module>
    from ._token_providers import *
  File "C:\Users\hanft\Documents\azuretestneu\.venv\lib\site-packages\azure\kusto\data\_token_providers.py", line 10, in <module>
    from azure.identity import ManagedIdentityCredential, AzureCliCredential
  File "C:\Users\hanft\Documents\azuretestneu\.venv\lib\site-packages\azure\identity\__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from ._credentials import (
  File "C:\Users\hanft\Documents\azuretestneu\.venv\lib\site-packages\azure\identity\_credentials\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .authorization_code import AuthorizationCodeCredential
  File "C:\Users\hanft\Documents\azuretestneu\.venv\lib\site-packages\azure\identity\_credentials\authorization_code.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .._internal.aad_client import AadClient
  File "C:\Users\hanft\Documents\azuretestneu\.venv\lib\site-packages\azure\identity\_internal\__init__.py", line 50, in <module>
    from .certificate_credential_base import CertificateCredentialBase
  File "C:\Users\hanft\Documents\azuretestneu\.venv\lib\site-packages\azure\identity\_internal\certificate_credential_base.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .persistent_cache import load_service_principal_cache
  File "C:\Users\hanft\Documents\azuretestneu\.venv\lib\site-packages\azure\identity\_internal\persistent_cache.py", line 9, in <module>
    import msal_extensions
  File "C:\Users\hanft\Documents\azuretestneu\.venv\lib\site-packages\msal_extensions\__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from .cache_lock import CrossPlatLock
  File "C:\Users\hanft\Documents\azuretestneu\.venv\lib\site-packages\msal_extensions\cache_lock.py", line 5, in <module>
    import portalocker
  File "C:\Users\hanft\Documents\azuretestneu\.venv\lib\site-packages\portalocker\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from . import portalocker
  File "C:\Users\hanft\Documents\azuretestneu\.venv\lib\site-packages\portalocker\portalocker.py", line 10, in <module>
    import pywintypes
  File "C:\Users\hanft\Documents\azuretestneu\.venv\lib\site-packages\win32\lib\pywintypes.py", line 105, in <module>
    __import_pywin32_system_module__("pywintypes", globals())
  File "C:\Users\hanft\Documents\azuretestneu\.venv\lib\site-packages\win32\lib\pywintypes.py", line 99, in __import_pywin32_system_module__
    assert sys.modules[modname] is not old_mod
```

When removing the line

```
from azure.kusto.data.helpers import dataframe_from_result_table
```

from the init file, everything works fine.

I tried reinstalling python and visual studio code.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: When did this error message occur ? Occurs when you want to deploy the function to azure or run the function on local ?

Comment: It occurs when running the function locally

Comment: Have you installed the module(`pip install azure-kusto-data`) success on local ?

Comment: Yes, it says "Requirement already satisfied: azure-kusto-data in c:\users\hanft\documents\azuretestneu\.venv\lib\site-packages (2.1.3)"

Comment: Could you please have a try to change the `.venv` path to another directory(such as "D" drive) or run your VS code with administrator.

Comment: How do I change the path?

Comment: You just need to create the function app in "D" drive and then when you generate the `.venv`, it will under "D".

Comment: I'm getting the same issue, except instead of your `from azure.kusto.data.helpers import dataframe_from_result_table` I have `from azure.identity import ClientSecretCredential`

Answer (score 0):

As the trace suggests, pywin32 is a transitive dependency of azure-identity, an authentication library azure-kusto-data uses ([azure-sdk-for-python#19989](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues/19989#issuecomment-901323886) has more detail on the problem, if you're curious). The latest version of azure-identity (1.6.1) imports that dependency only when necessary, to implement an optional feature. Happily, azure-kusto-data doesn't use that feature, so you should be able to work around this by upgrading azure-identity.